# Running 2 apps behind nginx

Tags: nginx

I don't know nginx yet. A devops guy set one up back a while for our app.

this is the `nginx.conf` he setup.

```
user www-data; 
worker_processes auto; 
pid /run/nginx.pid; 

events { 
worker_connections 768; 
multi_accept on; 
} 

http { 
sendfile on; 
tcp_nopush on; 
tcp_nodelay on; 
keepalive_timeout 65; 
types_hash_max_size 2048; 
include /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
default_type application/octet-stream; 
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE 
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; 
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; 
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log; 
gzip on; 
gzip_disable "msie6"; 


proxy_cache_path /home/html_catch levels=1:2 keys_zone=appbacktocartcocatch:2m max_size=50m; 
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args"; 
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m; 
proxy_cache_valid 404 1m; 




include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf; 




}
```

I can see that it `include`s some other files like this one which is for the app specifically

```
#proxy_cache_path /home/html_catch levels=1:2 keys_zone=appbacktocartcocatch:2m max_size=50m; 
#proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args"; 
#proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m; 
#proxy_cache_valid 404 1m; 


upstream appbacktocartco { 
# server localhost:3000; 
server localhost:3001; 
} 


server { 
listen 145.239.24.196:80; 
server_name app.backtocart.co; 

location / { 

proxy_cache appbacktocartcocatch; 

proxy_set_header Host $host; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
proxy_http_version 1.1; 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
proxy_pass http://appbacktocartco; 
proxy_read_timeout 90; 
} 


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot 
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.backtocart.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.backtocart.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot 
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot 
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot 


if ($scheme != "https") { 
return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
} # managed by Certbot 

}
```

Now I just need to run another app like this on port 5000. I just copied this file tried changing a few things, then restarted nginx but got some errors I don't understand. Can you help me with this?

**EDIT**

Here is just a way I tried

```
# proxy_cache_path /home/html_catch levels=1:2 keys_zone=appbacktocartcocatch:2m max_size=50m; 
# proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args"; 
# proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m; 
# proxy_cache_valid 404 1m; 


upstream appbacktocartco { 
  # server localhost:3000; 
  server localhost:5000; 
} 


server { 
listen 145.239.24.196:80; 
server_name chatservice.backtocart.co; 

  location / { 

    proxy_cache chatservicebacktocartcocatch; 

    proxy_set_header Host $host; 
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
    proxy_http_version 1.1; 
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
    proxy_pass http://chatservicebacktocartco; 
    proxy_read_timeout 90; 
  } 
}
```

Then I do

`/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

and get

```
[....] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

`systemctl status nginx.service` brings this

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-02-20 13:24:26 CET; 3min 4s ago
  Process: 28185 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 17317 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28188 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17319 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 20 13:24:26 ns3068281 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 20 13:24:26 ns3068281 nginx[28188]: nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "appbacktocartco" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chatservice.backtocart.co.conf:7
Feb 20 13:24:26 ns3068281 nginx[28188]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Feb 20 13:24:26 ns3068281 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 20 13:24:26 ns3068281 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Feb 20 13:24:26 ns3068281 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 20 13:24:26 ns3068281 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And `journalctl -xe` brings this

```
Feb 20 13:25:12 ns3068281 sshd[28260]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ts3 [preauth]
Feb 20 13:25:12 ns3068281 sshd[28260]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 20 13:25:12 ns3068281 sshd[28260]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=158.69.204.69
Feb 20 13:25:14 ns3068281 sshd[28260]: Failed password for invalid user ts3 from 158.69.204.69 port 45584 ssh2
Feb 20 13:25:14 ns3068281 sshd[28260]: Received disconnect from 158.69.204.69 port 45584:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Feb 20 13:25:14 ns3068281 sshd[28260]: Disconnected from 158.69.204.69 port 45584 [preauth]
Feb 20 13:26:00 ns3068281 nrpe[28264]: ERROR: my_system() seteuid(0): Operation not permitted
Feb 20 13:26:01 ns3068281 CRON[28267]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 20 13:26:01 ns3068281 CRON[28268]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 41 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Feb 20 13:26:01 ns3068281 CRON[28267]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 20 13:27:01 ns3068281 CRON[28310]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 20 13:27:01 ns3068281 CRON[28311]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 41 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Feb 20 13:27:01 ns3068281 CRON[28310]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 20 13:27:17 ns3068281 nrpe[28355]: ERROR: my_system() seteuid(0): Operation not permitted
Feb 20 13:27:47 ns3068281 sshd[28415]: Invalid user ts3 from 158.69.204.69
Feb 20 13:27:47 ns3068281 sshd[28415]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ts3 [preauth]
Feb 20 13:27:47 ns3068281 sshd[28415]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 20 13:27:47 ns3068281 sshd[28415]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=158.69.204.69
Feb 20 13:27:49 ns3068281 sshd[28415]: Failed password for invalid user ts3 from 158.69.204.69 port 38540 ssh2
Feb 20 13:27:49 ns3068281 sshd[28415]: Received disconnect from 158.69.204.69 port 38540:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Feb 20 13:27:49 ns3068281 sshd[28415]: Disconnected from 158.69.204.69 port 38540 [preauth]
Feb 20 13:28:01 ns3068281 CRON[28417]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 20 13:28:01 ns3068281 CRON[28418]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 41 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Feb 20 13:28:01 ns3068281 CRON[28417]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
lines 1012-1035/1035 (END)
```

Comment: Can you please add the error messages to your post?

Comment: @UwePlonus I added the details please take a look.

Comment: Did you change the server name? If you want both application to be reachable with the same server name then you have to modify the location. You cannot run two applications at the same server within root.

Comment: @UwePlonus one is `server_name app.backtocart.co` and the other is `server_name chatservice.backtocart.co`, isn't this ok?

Comment: This should be OK.

Comment: @UwePlonus but I get the error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the configuration files where you configure the upstreams:

```
upstream appbacktocartco { 
    # server localhost:3000; 
    server localhost:5000; 
}
```

You have to use different names for the upstream to make this work.

Also in the second config file you use

```
proxy_pass http://chatservicebacktocartco;
```

which must match the according upstream.

Also the error message (`nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "appbacktocartco"`) names this as a problem.

Comment: ok so I just update the configs. Restarted and got no errors. I update my dns. But the url doesn't work yet. However this is probably no more nginx problem, right?

Comment: Could also be related to nginx, but this would be another question. Please check first that your DNS is correct.

Comment: It seems to be everything ok with dns, maybe it's propagation issue?
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/chatservice.backtocart.co
though it seems to be ok in most places